# Как открыть доступ в интернет к определённому интернет-ресурсу?

Tags: windows, сеть, администрирование

В Windows, в сетевых настройках, не прописан адрес модема и адреса DNS серверов, необходимо открыть доступ одному или нескольким веб-ресурсам не открывая доступ в интернет(т. е. не вписывая адрес модема и адреса DNS серверов), сам компьютер подключён к локальной сети в которой есть доступ в интернет. Так вот, как открыть доступ к определённым ресурсам? Например Google.com? Возможно, что-то необходимо прописать в консоли? Явно указать адрес сайта, модема, DNS? Хотя адрес yandex например постоянно менятся(ip). Допустим DNS серверами я пропишу адрес модема в сетевых настройках, без адреса шлюза всё равно не будет интернета.

Comment: @Mike Не выход, это настройка для одной конкретной машины в сети.

Comment: так никто не мешает на роутере задать правила для конкретной машины

Comment: @Mike Рутами никак не получится такое сделать?

Comment: Чем чем ? Что такое "Руты"

Comment: Можно поставить локальный прокси-сервер (https://superuser.com/questions/57297/freeware-local-proxy-engine-for-windows), где можно ограничить/разрешить доступ к ресурсам по доменным именам, IP-адресам, портам-протоколам и так далее. Поскольку этот сервер локальный обойти его труда не составит. Разве что детишкам/бабушкам доступ закрываете.

Comment: Впрочем, если ваш "роутер" это не классический "роутер", то есть маршрутизатор, а современный комбайн всё-в-одном, то в нём должны быть функции файрвола и NAT. Соответственно, можно ограничить доступ к интернету, пусть и куцыми средствами. Поскольку файрвол в таких устройствах не является полноценным прокси-сервером, он может закрыть доступ по TCP/80, TCP/443 к определённым IP-адресам, но не к доменным именам.

Comment: @Mike route add

Comment: можно конечно. просто шлюз в настройках не указываете и прописываете его для конкретных ip. только это для мелких сайтов, висящих всегда на 1 ip поможет. А с тем же гуглом вы замучаетесь, во первых ip десятки, во вторых вам надо будет раз в час проверять не поменялись ли они. потому что у гугла есть кеш у крупных провайдеров. И в зависимости от текущих маршрутов в интернете может происходить переключение, адреса будут меняться

Comment: @Mike Так это всё таки возможно?

Comment: ну да, мне просто в голову сразу не пришло, потому что это извращение. прописывать десятки записей маршрутизации для каждого сайта, предварительно внимательно изучая все его страницы что бы узнать какие еще ресурсы надо открыть что бы он нормально открывался

Comment: @Mike Нужен один сайт только у которого статический IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно это можно сделать в разделе "родительский контроль" роутера изначально предназначенным для того чтобы на компьютере ребенка работали только "разрешенные" сайты.
Если это нельзя сделать, то можно попробовать руками:

1. Прописать в файле hosts ip адреса для нужных ресурсов
2. Прописать маршрут для заданных ip адресов

В windows это выглядит так: в windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts добавить строку `64.91.226.82 www.whois.com`
Выполнить команду с правами администратора `route add 64.91.226.82 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1` это при условии что шлюз в интернет 192.168.1.1

Недостатки такого вида ограничения в настоящее время очень существенны: сайт легко может "переехать" на другой ip адрес, часть контента может быть на других серверах, часть или вообще все скрипты делающие из текста сайт могут быть на другом адресе и т.д.